# customized email system

Tags: forms, email, drupal, dynamic

I have a need to add a personalized email form on each registered user's page. I would ordinarily use webforms but because the email form needs to dynamically change the destination email address to the email address of the registered user whose page a visitor is on.

From my research, Webforms can't dynamically change their destination address. Can anyone offer me some alternative solution(s).

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Incase anyone is interested in a solution to this problem - the answer is webforms.

The 6.x.3-1.1 version offers the ability to set a static email address or to a component field as a recipient address.
The component field is one of those that you configure as an input field for the webform. If you create an email component field you can set it as the recipient.